# Outbound fax using c# or 3rd party library?

Tags: c#, fax

I'm developing a fax solution wherein the application sends out fax. I have been researching about how to handle cases where the other line is answered by a person (and not a fax handshake). How did you handle this case?

Comment: Gonna need quite a bit more detail here.

Comment: Are you using Windows Fax Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a fax server that has a C# API (Facsys) - firstly i use an API call to send it a fax (in GIF format). Then, polling every 5 minutes, i ask the API what the status of that fax was: success, wrong number, no answer, no handshake (eg a person answered), etc. Works quite well.

Our research gave us two main options, being FacSys and MessageManager. I've had reasonable success with FacSys, but i've heard MM has better support.

Comment: unfortunately, the faxes i need to send out are to be delivered real time. how long does 1 fax (1 letter-sized page) usually take for your app to send?

Comment: To transmit it from my app to the fax server is pretty much instant, it certainly is quicker than it takes to actually send the fax (dialing, handshaking, transmitting, etc). We send out thousands of faxes a day on this thing. And No, its not spam.

Answer (score 2):

I just use an E-fax service. My C# application just sends out an email with the pdf document to fax in an attachment, and the fax number in the subject. I don't know if that would work for your case, but it's so much easier than writing a whole fax client from scratch.

If you really want to develop your own solution, there are probably some existing libraries that would help you communicate with the fax machines, but there are even E-fax solutions with flexible APIs that would let you do anything you need without futzing around with modems and whatnot.

Comment: e-fax is nice if there it supports other countries as well